# How to get PCA of the testing data?

Tags: machine-learning, pca, data-transformation, artificial-intelligence

I'd like to transform my data into pca (preprocessing data before I use data into classification model).
I separate my data into data training and data testing.

I used princomp in R to process pca with my data training, and I've got the loadings(eigenvector) of the pca data training.

Is it correct if I multiplied datatest with the loadings from the datatraining and get the scores of pca datatesting?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct; for any preprocessing done on the training set, the same must be done on the testing set.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it correct if I multiplied datatest with the loadings from the datatraining and get the scores of pca datatesting?

It depends on whether the you set `cor = TRUE` in your call to `princomp`. In any case, just use `predict` which will make sure to potentially scale, potentially center, and rotate the data. The code below shows both the "manual" way to get the result and by using `predict.princomp`

```r
pc.cr <- princomp(USArrests, cor = TRUE)
loadings(pc.cr)
#R 
#R Loadings:
#R          Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4
#R Murder    0.536  0.418  0.341  0.649
#R Assault   0.583  0.188  0.268 -0.743
#R UrbanPop  0.278 -0.873  0.378  0.134
#R Rape      0.543 -0.167 -0.818       
#R 
#R                Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4
#R SS loadings      1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00
#R Proportion Var   0.25   0.25   0.25   0.25
#R Cumulative Var   0.25   0.50   0.75   1.00

# get rotation without `princomp`
loads <- local({
  # use same scales as `princomp`
  X <- scale(as.matrix(USArrests), scale = 
               sapply(USArrests, function(x) sqrt(mean((x - mean(x))^2))))
  C <- cov(X)
  out <- eigen(C)$vectors
  dimnames(out) <- list(colnames(USArrests), paste0("PC", seq_len(ncol(X))))

  # we save the output from scale to later
  attributes(out) <- c(attributes(out), attributes(X)[c(
    "scaled:scale", "scaled:center")])
  out
})
loads # loadings are unique up to sign
#R             PC1    PC2    PC3    PC4
#R Murder   -0.536  0.418 -0.341  0.649
#R Assault  -0.583  0.188 -0.268 -0.743
#R UrbanPop -0.278 -0.873 -0.378  0.134
#R Rape     -0.543 -0.167  0.818  0.089
#R attr(,"scaled:scale")
#R   Murder  Assault UrbanPop     Rape 
#R     4.31    82.50    14.33     9.27 
#R attr(,"scaled:center")
#R   Murder  Assault UrbanPop     Rape 
#R     7.79   170.76    65.54    21.23 

# there is a predict function for class
class(pc.cr)
#R [1] "princomp"

# predict for first two rows
predict(pc.cr, newdata = USArrests[1:2, ])
#R         Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4
#R Alabama  0.986   1.13  0.444  0.156
#R Alaska   1.950   1.07 -2.040 -0.439

# reproduce the above
tmp <- scale(
  USArrests[1:2, ], scale = attr(loads, "scaled:scale"), 
  center = attr(loads, "scaled:center"))
tmp %*% loads # they are unique up to sign
#R            PC1  PC2    PC3    PC4
#R Alabama -0.986 1.13 -0.444  0.156
#R Alaska  -1.950 1.07  2.040 -0.439
```